# Is there a standard way to convert org.scalajs.dom.raw.Promise to Future's

Tags: scala.js

The raw [`org.scalajs.dom.raw.Promise`](https://github.com/bblfish/scala-js-dom/blob/d58d34f58d92dd4a72445392926aee16c7ef9aae/src/main/scala/org/scalajs/dom/raw/lib.scala#L475) is very close to the JS dom library. Is there a widely used library that transforms that into a scala.concurrent.Future ?

Comment: ASAIK, there isn't, which is arguably a crucial piece missing from the core library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scala.js 0.6.7 now comes with a [scala.scalajs.js.Promise](http://www.scala-js.org/api/scalajs-library/0.6.7/#scala.scalajs.js.Promise) and operations to translate to and from a scala Future, resolving the problems discussed in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good examples of how to do this online. These are not libraries, but at least it is something to go on. Here are two that relate to using IndexDB:

- [How to transform a Promise into a Future](https://github.com/viagraphs/scalajs-rx-idb/blob/919d0bc448e2548a3090bcc138d516a683ae1d25/src/main/scala/com/viagraphs/idb/IndexedDb.scala#L156)
- [How to transform a Promise into a monifu Observable](https://github.com/viagraphs/scalajs-rx-idb/blob/919d0bc448e2548a3090bcc138d516a683ae1d25/src/main/scala/com/viagraphs/idb/IndexedDb.scala#L188)

So that still leaves how to go the other way.

- [How to make an idiomatic Javascript library with Scala.js](http://pavkin.ru/how-to-make-an-idiomatic-javascript-library-with-scala-js/) gives some code examples for how to go from a Future to a `raw.Promise`